# Spring integration trigger timer events

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am still new to Spring Integration so please bear with me.

I have a use case where for each event received we have to create a set of timers that will be executed when it reaches that time frame. I am looking into Delayer but not sure if it will satisfy the above condition

Say for example when we receive a schedule event for a flight we will process, persist as per the business logic and will create 2 timers for the flight that will be executed after an hour. So when the clock reaches that hour mark it will perform some defined action.

I am thinking of "delayer" with a persistent message store but not sure if it is scalable for a huge load of 20k timers at a given time.

For debugging purposes I would also like to see the history of timer that are successfully executed and the details of the timer.

Please recommend a good approach.

Comment: I don't think this is asking for opinions, it rather asks for suggestions on how to approach the problem. This can very well be fact and expertise based, as the existing answer shows.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly : You are looking for Event based Dynamic Schedulers.

1. You can use REST (Event) & Quartz schedulers (Scheduling). Upon hitting URL localhost/schedule it will schedule the event as per the time give in your REST request.

Refer to below code sample

```
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.restro.jobs.request.ScheduleJobsRequest;
import com.restro.jobs.service.SchedulerService;

@Controller
public class JobsScheduleController implements ApplicationContextAware{

    @Autowired
    SchedulerService service;

    @Autowired
    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean;

    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/schedule", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { "application/json" })
    public @ResponseBody void schedule(@RequestBody ScheduleJobsRequest scheduleJobsRequest)
            throws JsonProcessingException, ClassNotFoundException, SchedulerException {
        Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
        scheduler.getContext().put("applicationContext", applicationContext);
        service.scheduleJobs(scheduleJobsRequest.getJobName(), scheduleJobsRequest.getGroup(),
                scheduleJobsRequest.getCronExpression(), scheduler);
        System.out.println("scheduled");
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

2. Sample REST Scheduling request

```
    {
    "jobName":"OrderOneSettlementJob",
    "group":"order",
    "cronExpression":"0/30 * * * * ?"
    }
```

Comment: If the application or the process is down then we could loose all the scheduled timers. Please let me know if my understanding is correct

Comment: @Developer Spring Batch Job Scheduler has below Database tables. Where it persist scheduler timers. Hence even if application goes down timer details will persist
`BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT
BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS
BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION
BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT`